# GuzzleHttp Client class not found in symfony2

Tags: symfony, http, guzzle

I have loaded in GuzzleHttp from

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/quickstart.html

and have the

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

When i call this action...

```
public function googlevolumeAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $searchStr = $data['search'];

        $client = new Client();
        $req = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:' .$searchStr, []);
        $decode = json_decode($req->getBody());
        $total = $decode->totalItems;
        $search = null;

        if ($total != 0) {
            $search = $decode->items;
        }

        return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:googlevolume.html.twig',
            ['items' => $search]);
}
```

I get this error...

```
Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace "GuzzleHttp".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Guzzle\Http\Client",     
"Guzzle\Service\Client", "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client", 
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client" or 
"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client"?
```

Any ideas why?

thanks

Comment: How did you install it in you application?

Comment: Yep in composer.json i have "require" "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^3.8" and have updated it and its in the vender folder

Comment: I think you may have an older version of guzzle installed.  I have "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"  Maybe check the Client class under vendor to see it's namespace.  It was different in earlier versions.  And disregard the comment about using \Guzzle... No need at all for a leading back slash.  And yes, guzzle 3.x is very old.  If you do need to use it then follow the appropiate docs.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a different version of guzzle installed than the docs you are looking at. From the error message you got it seems that if you change your use statement to:

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
```

It should work.